# Solicito ayuda con consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema con la siguiente consulta en MySQL:

```
SELECT nombre_completo 
FROM personas 
INNER JOIN alumnos ON personas.cedula = alumnos.ced_alumno 
INNER JOIN pertenece ON alumnos.ced_alumno= pertenece.ced_alumno 
INNER JOIN grupos ON pertenece.cod_grupo=grupos.cod_grupo 
WHERE personas.cedula=alumnos.ced_alumno 
      and grupos.turno=alumnos.posible_turno 
      and grupos.orientacion=alumnos.orientacion 
      and alumnos.ced_alumno != pertenece.cod_grupo
```

La intención es tomar todos los alumnos que no pertenezcan a a un grupo específico. Ej: Selecciono el grupo 1°BA, quiero tomar todos los alumnos que no pertenezcan a ese grupo. Los alumnos pueden pertenecer a más de un grupo por vez por eso la necesidad de tener una tabla "pertenece". Supongamos que tengo registrado a PEDRO y a JUAN, la CI de PEDRO está en el grupo 1°BA en la tabla pertenece, el código del grupo es 19. Entonces me quedaría ced_alumno=1234 y cod_grupo=19. Me interesa obtener el nombre de JUAN porque no está registrado en ningún grupo, y en caso de que el código del grupo cambiase por ejemplo a 20, se me mostrara a PEDRO nuevamente porque puede estar registrado en ese grupo. No sé si ha quedado claro, pero tengo un lío en la cabeza con esta consulta y después de muchas horas intentando resolverla no lo he logrado y por eso he recurrido aquí. Espero sus respuestas, muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Y esta consulta que datos regresa?, ¿hasta que parte funciona?, por favor lee [ask], edita y de ser posible crea un ejemplo verificable de la misma

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Necesitamos ver algunos datos de entrada, algunos de salida segun este query, y algunos de salida que vos querrias realmente.